# How to make Textarea and submit button in .php file hide for every row in database?

Tags: php, jquery, html

been working on some database data calling into a .php file.
The php file contains an "Add" button, a "textarea" and an "submit" button.

I did added some J Query script to it to make the "textarea and submit" button to hide until "add" button is clicked, and both "textarea and submit" to hide when "submit" button is clicked making "add" button reappear.

Ever thing is working fine but only glitch is, the script is only working for first row in the table, leaving the rest of rows uneffected.

I think i should use a loop or something.. spent couple of hours but couldn't able to figure it out by myself.

my script goes as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "the_database";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM input";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js">
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$().ready = function() {
 $('#text').hide();
    $('#textsubmit').hide();
    $("#addanswer").click(function() {
        $('#addanswer').hide();
        $('#text').fadeIn('slow').focus();
        $('#textsubmit').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $('#text').blur(function(){
        $('#text').hide();
        $('#textsubmit').hide();
        $('#addanswer').fadeIn('slow');
    });
}();
});//]]> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
?>
<button class="addanswer" id="addanswer"><B>Add Answer</B></button>
<form name="answer" method="post" action="output.php">
<textarea type="text" class="text" name="text" required id="text" placeholder="Please type your question here.."></textarea>
<button type="submit" id="textsubmit" class="textsubmit"><B>Submit</B></button>

</form>

<?php     }
    } else {
echo "0 results";
        }
    $conn->close();
?>
</body>
```

Comment: you can't have multiple html elements with the same id and you do not close the form either

Comment: i have only 3 id's there.... id for the button "addanswer", id for the textarea "text", and id for the submit button "textsubmit" .. all three are different names..    ?

Comment: You have multiple rows. And for each row the button ID, text, textsubmit IDs are same. So javascript always make the changes to the 1st occurrence. 

You can have those IDs with a index number appended, like #text_1, #text_2... and call a function on "onClick" event by passing that index number.

Once you have the index number, you can hide that specific element. 

the KEY is, you can have repeated IDs

Comment: please ignore the bit about not closing the form - I think I need a coffee

Comment: i m sorry @masterFly but i guess i quite didn't get you... so far what i understood is that you want me to change the id names for each row right.?.. in that case whenever i add a new row to the table i had to go to the script and change the name of id... ? how does it works... ?

Comment: Let me post an sample answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you cannot have multiple occurrences of the same ID, you could do something like this.

```
<?php
foreach( $your_data as $index => $data ){
    echo '<button class="addanswer" id="addanswer_'.$index.'"><B>Add Answer</B></button>';
    echo '<form style="display:none;" name="answer_'.$index.'" method="post" action="output.php">'; // I dont think openning form from row to row would be nice!
    echo '<textarea style="display:none;"  type="text" class="text" name="text" required id="text_'.$index.'" placeholder="Please type your question here.."></textarea>';
    echo '<button style="display:none;" onClick="addanswer('.$index.');" type="submit" id="textsubmit_'.$index.'" class="textsubmit"><B>Submit</B></button>';
    echo '</form>';
}
... Other code stuff.
```

Now the each row is having a different ID because we have used $index variable. And also we pass the $index to the javascript function as well. So the javascript can do what ever based on the $index value.

You can have your javascript function, something like this.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function addanswer(index){
    $('#addanswer_' + index).hide();
    $('#text_' + index).fadeIn('slow').focus();
    $('#textsubmit_' + index).fadeIn('slow');
}
</script>
```

Note: I havent checked this code by running it. I think you will get some understanding with this.

Thanks

Comment: My apologies for asking this... what should i be placing in the place of $your_data and &data..??

Comment: $your_data is what you get from the database. It should be a multi dimensional array. foreach loops the records. You dont need to replace $data. $data inside the loop is the current record tuple from the database

Comment: but in here i don't get anything from database... ?? although the mentioned script is for some other codes... @masterfly

Comment: Don't you get a result from DB with `$result = $conn->query($sql);` ??? I don't understand what are you saying

Comment: yaah.. but that is for another html script... in that script i am trying to retrive data from a table.. in here, i no need to retrive anything from DB.. so what should i be replacing in $your_data..? @masterfly

Comment: Please answer these questions,

1. In the displaying script are you not showing records you got from the database? 

2. What your `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ` loop does in this script?

3. What do you think `$result->fetch_assoc()` does in your 2nd script?

Comment: wait.. my bad.. so should i replace $your_data with "if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { "....?

Comment: Basically you are confused by foreach and while. You can use the while loop as well. Check the below.

`if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $index = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $index++;
        // stuff inside foreach goes here
    }
}`

Comment: you know what i m completely exhausted man.. but thanks for your patience and help... i wasted like 4 hours in this thing.. confused like hell... can you let me know your mail, so that i can forward you the updated script you can check on for me...

Comment: Can you take a look on this one man... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330887/slide-up-slide-down-is-not-working-for-selected-table-rows-from-db